# Design concerns for using 3x bit or one char(1) or one integer in table for holding status of item

Tags: sql-server, database-design, application-design

I need to extend my existing table with status column.
I am in doubt how to do that in most appropriate way regarding of future use of that status and performances of existing table.

My table is around 3,7 MIL records, and it is heavy read and write table.
Table represent stock (warehouse) of items (goods). It holds floats for many kind of prices and amounts, primary key is composite by item_id and warehouse_id.

Here is how I see ways to implement adding status of an item.

To add three more columns for statuses, each one column will represent some of statues,
Something like 'allow_sell','allow_orders','allow_returns'
I like this way because it uses BITs, (is it faster than varchar, or integer ?) and easy to understand what each status represents and which combination of statuses are seted on an item. In this way

To add one integer column called status_id and to add one more table statuses_of_item where I can hold description of each status and add statues as many as I wish.

To add one varchar(10) column where status will be written as dresption ('denay_all','allow_all', 'allow_orders_wo_sels' etc)

Have in mind that status is part of business logic and it uses only internal, Representation of statues are not displayed in SIMPLE WAY, statues not shown to users, it is only way how system should handle some situation in different places.

I think that 70% of items inside table will have default (same) status.
My database system is MS Sql Server 2008R2.

How I should design my table to include stautes ?

Comment: Perhaps a useful read: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/dry-principle

Comment: So these are attributes, basically, not statuses. The conceptual difference is important: purely logically, an instance of an item can only have one status, but it can have many attributes. While you have only thought of three now, how likely will it be that you will add many more attributes in the future?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, trying to encode multiple data points into a single column always ends up being more trouble than it's worth. Sure, it seems cool and clever to use BITWISE operators, but there are many things that go wrong and [it won't always be efficient to test those bits without cumbersome and unintuitive workarounds](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/dry-principle). It's the same reason we stay away from storing comma-separated lists, JSON strings etc. in a single column - eventually you care about viewing or filtering on those distinct bits which you now have to extract, sometimes expensively.

With the information I have, my vote is for three separate `BIT` columns. They will still collapse to similar storage patterns as a single column with the three bits on/off, and can be made more efficient individually and across the board in several ways, including:

- data compression
- sparse columns
- filtered indexes (e.g. `WHERE allow_returns = 1`)

Someone else advocated for three `CHAR(1)` columns. These do not benefit from storage collapse and also require a check constraint, making them less than ideal in my mind.

Now, my answer might change if you say, "well, what if I might add 15 other attributes in the future?" I certainly don't think it's wise to build the columns this way if they're not relatively static - changing the schema (and therefore all of the code and interfaces to it) for every new or changed attribute is going to be a royal pain. So in that case you might want to consider EAV - where the attributes are not part of the metadata but part of the data. There are a lot of objections to EAV, mostly around performance and the difficulty in enforcing constraints (in this case unlikely to be an issue if all of these attributes are either on or off), but [it worked quite well for us at my previous job](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway). You might model it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Attributes
(
  AttributeID TINYINT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ItemAttributes
(
  ItemID INT NOT NULL 
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Items(ItemID),
  AttributeID TINYINT NOT NULL 
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Attributes(AttributeID),
  Status BIT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ItemID, AttributeID)
);
```

And again, you can have filtered indexes here to make certain queries much more efficient, such as (imagine the AttributeID for "allow returns" is 10):

```
CREATE INDEX optAllowReturns ON dbo.ItemAttributes(ItemID)
  WHERE AttributeID = 10 AND Status = 1;
```

If you have certain attributes that are not on/off (for example, three states of manufacture or shipping), you can change the `Status` column to:

```
Value TINYINT NOT NULL
```

This can double as an on/off value for attributes that are represented that way, and as tri- or more-state value for attributes that require more than simple on/off. You can also reflect which type is which in the metadata of the `dbo.Attributes` table.

Comment: +1 for informative answer. I'd be interested to see though if in real life all this bit collapsing, compression etc. actually have any performance benefits over good ol' char(1)'s. I would imagine that if I were to index any of those 1-bit columns, or even all three of them, the index key will actually have 1 byte for each column anyway.

Comment: @mustaccio still not clear I understand your insistence on using CHAR(1). As I already pointed out, the OP does not expose these columns to users. And unlike BIT, you have to add check constraints, which are not free. So what does it *gain* you?

Comment: May be it's not much but maintainability. E.g. after some time you will want `allow_returns` to indicate not only "1" or "0", but also "yes, if in the original packaging". After some more time you will want to expose this column to the client, be that a human or an XML-based API call. Also, given the current state of education, it's not guaranteed that a future business analyst will understand "1" and "0" as easily as "Y" and "N" when trying to reverse engineer metadata for the then-legacy system...

Comment: @mustaccio well I think that's a very subjective thing and very hand-wavy. The constraints alone point me the other way. It is also not crazy to change a BIT to TINYINT and use an enum with a foreign key, if you anticipate those kinds of changes. Not every piece of data in a database needs to be understood by the business analyst, *especially* when those columns are not exposed to them directly, but rather through checkboxes, drop-down lists, etc. I still don't feel you've made a strong case that CHAR(1) has any significant advantage over BIT in *this case*.

Comment: I'm not really trying make a case for CHAR columns; just want to understand advantages of the alternative. And what's wrong with check constraints?

Comment: @mustaccio Do you think check constraints are free? You have to remember to add them, they have to be included in your source, you have to account for those violations in your error handling, and SQL Server has to actively check each one of them on an insert/update. I'd rather take advantage of the automatic validation that comes with the data type than have to scaffold my own on top of it. All in case I forget that 1 means on and 0 means off? *shrug* We're just going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Nothing in this world is free. You will spend extra cycles validating your data, whether in the database or in the application, sure. On the other hand, the query optimizer can make use of a check constraint if it exists.

Comment: Thank you! It did indeed seemed cool and clever to use BITWISE operators, until I had to serialize the field to human readable output and write test cases for it. Came here for confirmation that I made a mistake and I'm reworking the project to use 4 bit fields instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to model each independent data item as its own predicate (column).

If you are sure that each of your status codes will remain binary, then use a `bit` column for each.  Bit is an efficient data type for storage.  Note, however, that you shouldn't try to filter (WHERE) on a bit field if you can help it.  Bit is not generally something you can effectively index.

If you choose to have a status column which is a foreign key to a status description lookup table, then have one FK status column for each independent status.  Don't comingle selling, ordering and returning.

Comment: I do including statuses because of filtering, One of my common task is to extract only items with some status for one warehouse

Comment: However filtered indexes with where clauses on bit columns can be very effective.

Comment: @adopilot - Depending on how selective your bit columns are, full table indexes on bit columns _can_ be helpful.  In other words, if only a small minority of your rows have a bit flag with a given value (0 or 1) and you are always looking for that more rare value, then a full table index will be helpful.  In other conditions, you can use filtered indexes as correctly suggested by Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

A single 3-bit column, as well as 3 separate 1-bit columns, will occupy 1 byte of storage for each row, which saves you a whopping 7 MB for the entire table, compared to using human-friendly CHAR(1) columns for each flag, such as `ALLOW_RETURNS CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT CHECK (ALLOW_RETURNS IN ('Y','N'))`.

Comment: You're forgetting that up to 8 BIT columns can collapse into a single byte, so 3 individual BIT columns can also be accomplished without this "whopping" 7 MB of extra space (I don't know that you really need to make the storage a more friendly Y/N - are people fiddling with the bits on disk, or are the options exposed to them by checkboxes etc. at the UI layer?). Also consider sparse columns, compression, etc.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I said - the 3 bit column will occupy 1 byte, which gives you insignificant space savings. I doubt the performance difference between 3 bit columns and 3 char(1) columns will be noticeable though. On the other hand, in my view character flags are better from the application development and maintenance perspective, because they are self-documenting.

Comment: Oh, the wording made me think you were advocating a single column that contained a bitwise value. Suggest re-wording from "a 3-bit column" to "3 bit columns". Also 1 (true) and 0 (false) are also IMHO self-documenting (even though the OP said "not shown to users"), and as BIT columns they have the benefit of collapsing storage-wise and also not requiring check constraints.

Comment: Can you show the table definition that includes a single 3-bit column?

Comment: What I meant was a tinyint with the bit map for the three indicators; you would only need 3 bits out of 8 but would store 8 anyway.